# Custom infix operators and optionals

Tags: swift, swift5

```
class TreeNode: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: TreeNode, rhs: TreeNode) -> Bool {
        lhs.val == rhs.val && lhs.left == rhs.right && lhs.right == rhs.left
    }
    
    var val: Int = 0
    var left, right: TreeNode?
}
```

This code compiles and even works. But why? `left` and `right` variables are optional, isn't I supposed to unwrap it first in the body of `static func ==`?

Actually it isn't quite an equation. As you can see it's rather some sort of symmetrical equation. So I would like to define custom operator with different name for this purpose:

```
infix operator =|=: ComparisonPrecedence
class TreeNode {
    static func =|=(lhs: TreeNode, rhs: TreeNode) -> Bool {
        lhs.val == rhs.val && lhs.left =|= rhs.right && lhs.right =|= rhs.left
    }
    
    var val: Int = 0
    var left, right: TreeNode?
}
```

And now it doesn't compile due to the reason I've mentioned earlier. It wants me to unwrap the optionals first.
Actually it would be great if it "just works" like in the case of "=="))) Because not having to unwrap the optionals explicitly would be convenient here.

So I want to understand why it behaves differently in these two situations.

Comment: `Comparison` it is for sorting. It is not the same as `Equatable`. If `a` and `b` are optionals. `a == b` is OK `a < b` it is not.

Comment: @Leo Dabus But why a=|=b is not Ok if a, b are optionals?

Comment: `a = 1` and `b = nil` `a == b` is false, `a = nil` and `b = 2` `a == b` is false, comparing `a = 1` and `b = nil` `a < b` is ???

Comment: @Leo Dabus Yes, I'm agree. We are talking about Equatable here. There is no code related to Comparison. I'm interested in Equatable situation only.

Comment: So implement its operator `==` and forget about a custom operator. There is no `"EquatablePrecedence"`

Comment: @Leo Dabus I guess you probably confused with ComparisonPrecedence. It's deferent. It's Precedence. It has nothing about Comparison protocol :)

Comment: I now what `Precedence` is and how to conform to `Comparable` protocol I just don't understand the goal of using `=|=` instead of `==`

Comment: @Leo Dabus "implement its operator == and forget about a custom operator" is indeed one of possible solutions. But I want to understand why it's the case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code compiles and even works. But why?

It is simply because there is an [`==` operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/2950146) declared for all `Optional<Wrapped>` where `Wrapped` is `Equatable`, like this:

```
static func == (lhs: Wrapped?, rhs: Wrapped?) -> Bool
```

`TreeNode` is `Equatable` in your first code snippet, so it works.

In your second code snippet, you haven't declared a `=|=` operator that operates on two `TreeNode?`. You can do that by either putting this in global scope...

```
func =|= (lhs: TreeNode?, rhs: TreeNode?) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (nil, nil): // both nil
        return true
    case (let x?, let y?): // both non-nil
        return x =|= y // compare two non-optional tree nodes
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

or writing an `Optional` extension:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == TreeNode {
    static func =|= (lhs: Wrapped?, rhs: Wrapped?) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (nil, nil): // both nil
            return true
        case (let x?, let y?): // both non-nil
            return x =|= y // compare two non-optional tree nodes
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

But as Leo Dabus said, I'd just conform to `Equatable` and not create your own operator. Conforming to existing protocols allows you to use `TreeNode` with many APIs in the standard library, such as `Array.contains(_:)`.

Comment: This kind of explanation is exactly what I needed, thank you. But there is a problem. I tried to define =|= with optional arguments already (exactly like you suggest). It doesn't compile: "Member operator '=|=' must have at least one argument of type 'TreeNode'". I don't know why. I can't find any info why it must have at least one non-optinonal argument.

Comment: @Roman You should put it in the _global scope_, that is, outside of any class/struct.

Comment: "case (let x?, let y?): // both non-nil" It's a very weird syntax. Shouldn't it be just case (let x, let y) or case let (x, y).

Comment: @Roman It's called the [Optional Pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#ID520). It only matches non nil values, whereas `let x` will match nil values as well as non nil values.

Comment: @Roman Is there any remaining questions about this that you have?  "'Member operator '=|=' must have at least one argument of type 'TreeNode''. I don't know why." because a type can only define operators that operate on itself. `Optional<TreeNode>` is not the same as `TreeNode`. This is why you should declare the operator in an `Optional` extension, or in the global scope.